# Gridview_SelectedIndexChanged persisting upon refresh of page?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview where when I select a row, the code within Gridview_SelectedIndexChanged will occur. However, I notice when I refresh, the debugger goes into this method still? So when I refresh or come back to the page it's like the user clicked the row he left off on. Here's my .aspx gridview code:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="gridview1" CellPadding="8" runat="server" AllowPaging="True"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="testdb" onclick="RowCommand" 
    onselectedindexchanged="MsgInbox_SelectedIndexChanged" PageSize="25" 
    AllowSorting="True" OnRowCreated="Gridview_RowCreated" 
    OnRowDataBound =   "MsgInbox_RowDataBound" DataKeyNames = "primaryKey"
```

Comment: When you click on a row the gridview causes the page to do a postback. It is default browser behavior to try to post again upon refresh.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844403/async-partial-postback-datagrid-issues/15847762#15847762) maybe useful

Comment: If you are talking about browser refresh its normal behaviour. On refresh of a screen the browser posts back the same data again. Here are some links to help you understand it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308723/is-there-a-difference-between-an-f5-browser-refresh-and-postbackasp-net http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19366/Handling-ASP-NET-Browser-Refresh